# Opening dev tools in Firefox repositions my CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, dom, positioning

I am a newb to CSS, so this could be really easy or perhaps not.

Essentially, my html looks like this.

```
<div class= "main-container">
    <div class= "searchResults">
        <div class= "searchResultsView">
            <div app-view-segment= "2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class= "noResultsMessage" ng-show= "noResults">
            <h2> Sorry, no results for {{searchQuery}} </h2>
        </div>
        <div class= "searchResultsPageNumbers">
            <footer>
                <pagination total-items= "totalSymbols" ng-model= "currentPage" ng-change= "pageChanged" max-size= 10></pagination>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this.

```
.searchResults{
    position: static;
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%;
}

.searchResultsView{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.noResultsMessage{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.searchResultsPageNumbers{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 38%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

So essentially, I've got a block called "searchResults", that contains the results, the message if we don't have results, and the page numbers.

This is looking ok, until I open the dev tools (f12 in fire fox). Once I open the tools, the page numbers get repositioned to the center of the page (or more precisely, just north of the dev tools window). The other things on the page get repositioned slightly, but the page numbers are effected the most. I suspect this is because I positioned them relative to the bottom of "searchResults" rather than the top, but regardless...

What is the CSS I need to write such that the dev tools will simply cover the page numbers when opened, and not reposition them to the center of the page? As you can see, I tried setting the z-index to -1 in the hopes this would be effective, and it was not.

Comment: change the position of `searchResults` to relative. Making the absolutes inside be positioned relative his parent.

Comment: This reacted wildly... the page numbers went up to the top of the page. Does the relative -> absolute need to cascade all the way up to the top of the document? This particular bit of html I am passing in as a segment via some angular code

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't think I have access to either due to being at work :/

Comment: Think Danko is on to it -- a higher level question though -- why are your elements all being positioned?

Comment: I don't know. As I said, I am new to CSS and have pretty much messed around with it until it looked ok, not knowing the rationale or philosophy behind things. When I get a chance, I'm going to refactor, but now is not the time.

Comment: I seem to have fixed my problem by making "searchResults" fixed and the things inside it relative... don't know how good of a fix this will ultimately be though.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed my problem by making "searchResults" fixed and the things inside it relative... don't know how good of a fix this will ultimately be though, so I won't mark the answer as accepted just yet.